# JTable Cell with window focus in JAVA Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have created `JTable` with `TableModel` in which I make column `Product Id` as editable. This jtable is shown when i click one `cashMemoBtn` and if i type `product id` in first row and hit enter key then it is adding new empty row to jtable. But my problem is when new Empty row is added then `Product Id` Cell should have `blicking` cursor like we see in any editor OR in textfield.

I have attached my expected output screenshot here

[image: for your reference]

In image you can see vertical bar which is indicating current focus but i want it should be automatic for all new rows when i add new rows.

I tried with

`jTable.setEditingColumn(1);
jTable.setEditingRow(0);`

But is not working as per my requirement. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After you add the empty row of data to the table you then need to start editing on the desired cell.

The basic code would be:

```
if (table.editCellAt(row, 1))
{
    Component editor = table.getEditorComponent();
    editor.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. But it is not working for first empty row(which is created on when i click `cashMemoBtn`)

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem showing how you implemented the suggestion.